# Application which loads a DLL works in MSDEV but fails at command line

Tags: c++, windows, command-line

I have an application which, depending on a passed in parameter, will dynamically load a DLL.

When I run it in either debug or release from MSDEV 2008 environment it works fine.
When I run it in either debug or release from the command prompt it fails to the load the DLL.

The parameters are the same, I copied/pasted them.

Is there a difference in the way exes are called from the command prompt and the development environment?

Comment: you are running the exe from command prompt from the same directory where the exe exists?

Comment: What error code are you getting? Have you tried using Dependency Walker?

Comment: @Naveen, good question - yes I am.

Comment: @AlanStokes, I get "Error (2) - Failed to initialise dll."  I have not used dependancy walker, would that help?  The DLL builds and runs fine from the developer environment so I assumed that that would imply the DLL was fine and the problem was in the exe loading process, did I miss something?

Comment: @SteveTaylor: I would try 2 things for testing purposes: (1). Pass the absolute path of the dll to the AfxLoadLibrary and see what happens (2). Check whether some other working directory is specified(i.e. other than the default one is specified in the VS project properties).

Comment: @Steve Dependency Walker is really good at showing where the failure is in such cases. The problem could be path-related; it may well be failing to load some remote dependency rather than your DLL specifically.

Comment: *sigh* The problems is that I am an idiot.  The arguments were NOT the same between dev environment and batch file/command line.  The command line used the %datestr% macro and the dev environment used an actual date.  This did not cause a problem previously so I stopped seeing it as a potential issue *slaps forehead*  Now it works, sorry for wasting your time and thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with VS2010, but I'm pretty sure that this won't make any difference. When executing from VS, the working directory is set to the directory which contains your code files (if not changed in the project properties), when starting it via command line it is set to the directory which the command line is currently working with (the text in front of the ">"). You'll have to use "cd" to change your working directory to the path containing your DLL.

Comment: Thanks, I will bear that in mind.  However, the issue was just me being an idiot!  (Have a look at the comments to the above answer).

Comment: Ah ok, never mind, I've overlooked the "Show 2 more comments" 'button'.